# Fully replace a record with unbound PostgreSQL cursor

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, database-cursor

Is it possible to use unbound cursors to fully edit and replace a row in a table?

I'm using unbound cursors since the table is dynamically specified with a parameter, but I can't use the "UPDATE table SET column = value WHERE" syntax since the columns are unspecified.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trim_table(in_table TEXT) AS $$
  DECLARE
    ref REFCURSOR;
    current_row RECORD;
BEGIN
  OPEN ref FOR EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM '|| quote_ident(in_table);
  LOOP
    FETCH ref INTO current_row;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    current_row = my_row_function(current_row);
    /*How can I replace my row here?*/
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE ref;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

All the example and answers I found show only how to update a single field and not the full record.

Comment: what do you need to do in your 'my_row_function'?

Comment: Specifically, trim away every whitespace from text fields

Comment: when you say trim away : whitespaces that are in the middle of your text field too? (I couldn't connect to answer before : sorry for that ;) ) I have an idea to solve your problem without any cursor and I think very much faster if you want it.

Comment: No, I want only to trim away mistyped whitespaces at the beginning or at the end of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code can help you in some ways :

```
select 
    string_agg('UPDATE '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||chr(13)||' SET '||column_name||' = TRIM('||column_name||')', '; '||chr(13)) into query
from information_schema.columns
where data_type in ('varchar', 'text')
    and table_schema = 'your_schema'
    and table_name = 'your_table_name';

execute query;
```

Put it in your procedure, modify it to your convenience, and you will no longer need this loop.

Comment: Wouldn't that trim the spaces in the column name? I'm trying to trim the records

Comment: to see what is going to be executed : remove the 'into query' part and do the select with your table and schema name. You'll see if it is what you want ;)

Comment: To answer your comment more properly : I do not update row by row here. I update all the values in all the text and varchar columns of a given table.

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this! I added "character varying" to the datatypes and a query length check and it works!  

Although it doesn't answer the direct question, this is what I really wanted to do since the beginning.

Comment: In many cases the best way to expose a problem to this community is to express directly your basic needs, not the your technical problem but the very functionnal problem. I am pleased that this helped.

Comment: And remember one thing : when you think that a cursor is your solution in RDBMS development that is you are thinking wrong in most cases.